# Activar Barra de Desplazamiento Windows Form

Tags: windows-forms

quisiera saber como puedo activar la barra de desplazamiento para un Windows Form el cual aparezca desde el diseño asi exactamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es antes de iniciar la aplicacion, pero no recuerdo como fue que lo puse espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos.

Comment: Puedes postear tu código.

Answer (score 0):

WindowsForm, tiene la propiedad AutoScroll, puedes asignarlo true o false.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/110339)

Comment: En serio?? La propiedad AutoScroll activa o desactiva el scroll... eso responde la pregunta según creo yo... perdón por no responderla a tu gusto.